# Django MEDIA_URL again ... Unhandle

Tags: django, deployment

my settings.py file

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/path/to/htdocs/mysite/public/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

in site_media i have my images and CSS
...`href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/style.css"` ... (with {{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css is this same)

after render it look like this
`href="/site_media/style.css"`

but at http://example.com/site_media/style.css there is Unhandled Exception (i thing no url mapped in urls.py)

everything is work fine in DEBUG mode because i have this in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')}),
    (r'^site_media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')}),
)
```

but what I need to do when `DEBUG = False`

Answer (score 1):

what is happening is that in DEBUG mode django serves your style.css file. You tell it to do that with this line

```
(r'^site_media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')}),
```

)

But this line does not go into the `urlpatterns` variable when debug is false. To test that try to access `localhost:8000/site_media/style.css` when debug is true (should work) and when it is false (will give a 404 error).

You could just leave out the

```
if settings.DEBUG:
```

part, but that means that django would still serve static files and that is not recommended in production for performance reasons.

In a production setup you should use a different webserver to serve your static files. I have had good experiences with [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) running in front of apache.

This is an excellent tutorial which shows you how to create such a setup:
http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/tutorials/django-deployment-guide-ubuntu

Be prepared though that creating a production setup is not quite as painless as just typing `python manage.py runserver`. I have also heard good things about using nginx together with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) and that that makes setting up a production server much simpler, but have no experience with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve them somehow yourself.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server

In production, use something like `Apache` or `Nginx` to serve your static files.

Basically, you map a URL (in your case `/site_media/`) in the server to a folder on your server (like wherever your media directory is now) and you're done. All requests to `/site_media/` now don't go to your app but go searching the directory for static files to serve.

Implementation depends on which server setup you go for.